Pi4 : use both hmdi outputs with independent graphical display instances
I would like to craft a raspberry pi 4 (or 5) based solution that can use both HDMI display outputs, but with two independent desktop instances :

first display is the regular desktop (with a user using it)
second is a display only desktop (no input interactions)

It is not the classic behavior of "dual screen" with one desktop on two screens (with windows that can be moved on each screen), I would like second display to be totally independant and non-interactive (like if I have a secondary raspberry pi built for digital signage).
I don't know if it would be X11 or wayland, but I rather prefer having hardware acceleration...
